# Using sed command in shell script for substring and replace position to need

Tags: bash, shell, sed, substring

I’m dealing data on text file and I can’t find a way with sed to select a substring at a fixed position and replace it.

This is what I have:

```
X|001200000000000000000098765432|1234567890|TQ
```

This is what I need:

```
‘X’,’00000098765432’,’1234567890’,’TQ’
```

The following code in sed gives the substring I need (00000098765432) but not overwrites position to need

```
echo “ X|001200000000000000000098765432|1234567890|TQ” | sed “s/
*//g;s/|/‘,’/g;s/^/‘/;s/$/‘/“
```

Could you help me?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to delete the first 4 chars.  Is that correct?

Comment: If extracting data with pipeline, I want to remove 16 character in front of position two. 

sample: 001200000000000000000098765432 to 00000098765432

Comment: Your code and example are using "smart quotes", please [edit] those to use plain ASCII quotes instead, `'` and `"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put the quotes in, I'd still use `awk`.

```
$: awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{q="\047"} {print  q $1 q","q substr($2,17,14) q","q $3 q","q $4 q"\n"}' <<< "X|001200000000000000000098765432|1234567890|TQ"
'X','00000098765432','1234567890','TQ'
```

If you just want to use `sed`, note that you *say* above you want to remove 16 characters, but you are actually only removing 14.

```
$: sed -E "s/^(.)[|].{14}([^|]+)[|]([^|]+)[|]([^|]+)/'\1','\2','\3','\4'/" <<< "X|0012000000000000000098765432|1234567890|TQ"
'X','00000098765432','1234567890','TQ'
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `sed`, I would use `awk` for this.

```
echo "X|001200000000000000000098765432|1234567890|TQ" | awk 'BEGIN {FS="|";OFS=","} {print $1,substr($2,17,14),$3,$4}'
```

Gives output:

```
X,00000098765432,1234567890,TQ
```

Here is how it works:

`FS` = Field separator (in the input)

`OFS` = Output field separator (the way you want output to be delimited)

`BEGIN` -> think of it as the place where configurations are set. It runs only one time. So you are saying you want output to be comma delimited and input is pipe delimited.

`substr($2,17,14)` -> Take $2 (i.e. second field - awk begins counting from 1 - and then apply substring on it. 17 means the beginning character position and 14 means the number of characters from that position onwards)

In my opinion, this is much more readable and maintainable than sed version you have.

Comment: `substr($2,17,14)` could just be `substr($2,17)`, you don't need to specify how many characters if you just want to go to the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed "s/|\(0[0-9]\{15\}\)\?/','/g;s/^\|$/'/g" input_file
'X','00000098765432','1234567890','TQ'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v del1="\047" \
    -v del2="," \
    -v start="3" \
    -v len="17" \
    '{
         gsub(substr($0,start+1,len),"");
         gsub(/[\|]/,del1 del2 del1);
         print del1$0del1
    }' input_file

'X',00000098765432','1234567890','TQ'
```

Comment: @EdMorton: changed to len

Answer (score 0):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ echo 'X|001200000000000000000098765432|1234567890|TQ' |
awk -F'|' -v OFS="','" -v q="'" '{sub(/.{16}/,"",$2); print q $0 q}'
'X','00000098765432','1234567890','TQ'
```

Answer (score 0):

not as elegant as I hoped for, but it gets the job done :

```
'X','00000098765432','1234567890','TQ'

    # gawk profile, created Mon May  9 21:19:17 2022
    # BEGIN rule(s)

    'BEGIN {
     1     _ = sprintf("%*s", (__ = +2)^++__+--__*++__,__--)
     1            gsub(".", "[0-9]", _)
     1             sub("$",     "$", _)
     1    FS = "[|]"
     1   OFS = "\47,\47"
    }

    # Rule(s)

     1     (NF *= NF == __*__) * sub(_,  "|&",   $__) * \
        sub("^.*[|]", "", $__) * sub(".+", "\47&\47")    }'
```

Tested and confirmed working on `gnu gawk 5.1.1`, `mawk 1.3.4`, `mawk 1.9.9.6`, and `macosx nawk`

— `The 4Chan Teller`